# How to get files[0] or [object File] of certain file populated by using its full path?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, filesystemobject

I'm trying to make the user click once on a button with on-click function and initiate file upload, without making him pick the file through clicking first on "Choose File" which opens file dialog box.
Is this possible through populating the files[0] object array or [object File] if I have the full absolute path of such a file ?

Comment: Imagine a random page accessing files on your computer...

Comment: Ok, I got what you mean But do you know the structure of files[0] object array or [object File] can you give me a simple example please

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Answer (score 1):

No, without user input allowing javascript direct access to the user's file system would pose a large security risk.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript#372333) answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer But do you know the structure of files[0] object array or [object File] can you give me a simple example please.